# How does Windows obtain and display My Computer System Version

Tags: windows, version, system

Good day

In Windows when My Computer properties window is opened, there is a General tab with 'System' information. For example, on my Windows it says:

System:
  Microsoft Windows XP
  Professional x64 Edition
  Version 2003
  Service Pack 2

Where does Windows get this information? Modifications in 'CurrentVersion' key of the registry and 'prodspec.ini' file do not change this output.

Thanks

Comment: It uses the Dr Seuss Algorithm: const wchar_t* VersionName = L"I am Sam, I am";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows kernel stores its version as a global variable. On creation of a new process, the OS version is copied into the process' [Process Environment Block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Environment_Block) (which is accessible from user mode). The process gets the version by calling the WINAPI `GetVersion()`, which retrieves the version simply by reading it from the Process Environment Block.

You can use a debugger on explorer.exe to see that it indeeds calls `GetVersion()` when you open up the My Computer properties window.